# Cross-thread operation is detected после завершения метода. Как отладить?

Tags: c#, wpf

Имеется BackgroudWorker для заполнения таблицы GridView из БД.

В первой итерации загрузки всё проходит нормально все методы выполняются ничего не падает. При второй итерации падает после завершения метода и понять на какой объект  падает исключение не представляется возможным. Например:

```
 // первый метод, запросить данные по двойному клику.
private void Control_OnMouseDoubleClick() { 
      bw.RunWorkerAsync(row);
 }

private void BwOnDoWork(...) { 
    // пытаюсь обновить данные привязанные к GridView который в главном потоке
    // но сейчас мы находимся не в главном потоке и исключение не падает, загружаю в таблицы
    maindatatable.fill(loadmethod1(row.id));
    secondtable.fill(loadmethod12(row.id));
    //беру данные с второй таблице по связке с первой
    var childrows = row.CreateChildView(...);
    // возвращаю какой-то результат
    doWorkEventArgs.Result = object;
 }

private void BwOnRunWorkerCompleted(){
    // здесь мы снова в главном потоке, получаю результат
    var res = runWorkerCompletedEventArgs.Result as DataRowView;
   // присваиваю вторую таблицу динамически для вывода деталей
   secondgrid.ItemsSource = res;
}
```

Конкретно в этом варианте на второй итерации падает сразу после MouseDoubleClick. Когда я переписал загрузку данных в отдельных Task то стало падать после WorkerCompleted, но это и так звучит странно, мы и так находимся в другом потоке и потом еще в третьем потоке грузим данные. Как нибудь можно посмотреть на какую из таблиц падает? Или нужно как то выносить объединение данных с базы и те что сейчас у клиента на экране?

Comment: что написано в stacktrace и в exception message ?

Comment: @tym32167 В exception message ничего что могло бы помочь, общая ошибка 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in WindowsBase.dll
Additional information: A cross-thread operation is detected.
В StackTace курсор стоит на методе WindowsBase.dll!System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.TryCatchWhen(...)

Comment: @ヒミコ ну очепятка же, поправил

Comment: @tym32167 Всё дошло до меня. Я поставил точку останова в методе который выполнялся асинхронно и понял что падает в нем и нашел объект соответственно на котором падает. У меня таблицы привязаны к гридам уже, и я хотел их обновить выполнив метод Fill уже на существующих таблицах. Так как они уже в главном потоке поэтому не дает их обновлять. Придется их объединять с таблицей которая будет запрашиваться отдельно новым объектом.